# Any API to read Geo location data from Windows 7

Tags: geolocation, geocoding

Is there any way to read the geo location formation through WI-FI in windows 7 ? I have used **System.Device.Location** and its not able to fetch the Geo Data. Also i have installed Geosense 64 bit but not working and error message for Geosense is - The device Geosense Location Sensor (location (unknown)) is offline due to a user-mode device crash. Please note that i can not use html5/Javascript as the required application has to a be windows 7 service.

Answer (score 0):

In general the System.Device.Location is made for positioning only, if you want to use Geo services with WP7, then you would need to use the GeocodeServiceClient.

For examples, check my old [Maps Examples for Windows phone](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Maps_Examples_for_Windows_phone), and see the Geo Coding  & Reverse Geo coding  examples from there.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I want to fetch only latitude/longitude values in windows 7 through Wi-Fi, not from GPS device.